# jboss not starting in debug mode with breakpoints

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

my local jboss server is starting in normal mode, and I am able to access my application. I wanted to debug my java web application , so I put the breakpoints and tried to start the server in debug mode. but it is unable to start server in debug mode. then I removed all my breakpoints ,now my server is starting in debug mode. but now I can't see step into & step out buttons enabled( I think as there is no breakpoints set). my goal is to get understatnd the the process flow for a particular request. can anybody help me out in this ,if I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

How did you start it in debug mode?

Perhaps is something like this:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8001
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

Maybe with export instead of set if you are in Unix env. The second part is listening to that port from wherever you have your code. Eclipse? Netbeans? Set a debug configuration (Remote Java Application listening in the defined port, in case you use Eclipse) and start the debug configuration. Now your IDE will show you when execution reaches your breakpoint.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have set this in run.bat file of jboss          "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044". so now i need to set this 1044 as the listening port from my eclipse  right?

Comment: with this , i can the  that " vm is trying to connect to port 1044", but its not connecting. so no  response . but with netstat ,i do see that 1044 is listening to jboss

Comment: Look here for walkthrough with screenshots http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html?page=6